# Cross validation or EM for selecting strength of the prior?

Tags: bayesian, cross-validation, expectation-maximization, out-of-sample

Often when I'm looking at bayesian analyses, the influence of the prior is chosen via cross validation. For example, suppose $X$ and $Y$ represent some real valued data that I want perform a bayesian linear regression on to estimate $Y$ from $X$. This can be formulated as:

${\hat a} = argmin_a \ \sum_i    \|y_i-ax_i\|^2_2 + \lambda \| a^Ta \|$

The sum of squares loss imposes the model $p(y|x,a) = \mathbb{N}(y|\mu_y + ax, \Sigma_{yy} - a^T\Sigma_{xx}a)$ and regularization an isotropic gaussian on $A$ that $p(a) = \mathbb{N}(a| 0, \lambda^{-1} I)$. So this is equivalent to the objective

$\hat{a} = argmax_{a} \ \log \ p({\bf y}, a|{\bf x}, \lambda)$

$ \ \ = argmax_{a} \ \log \ p(a| \lambda) \Pi_i \ p(y_i|x_i,a) $

In cross validation - you might initialize $\lambda$ to many different parameters to pick the one with the best out-of-sample error.

But I thought this just looked like a bit of a dirty hack. Would it be better to maximize the model evidence, i.e. marginalize out $a$ (resulting in a more complex optimization involving expectation-maximization)? This is, for the first step of choosing $\lambda$

$ {\hat \lambda} = argmax_{\lambda} \ \log \ \ p({\bf y}| {\bf x}, \lambda)$

$ \ \ = argmax_{\lambda} \ \log \ \int \ p({\bf y}, a| {\bf x}, \lambda)da$

$ \ \ = argmax_{\lambda} \ \log \ \int p(a| \lambda) \Pi_i \ p(y_i|x_i,a)da$

Once $\lambda$ has been selected via this procedure, choose $a$ by

${\hat a} = argmin_a \ \sum_i    \|y_i-ax_i\|^2_2 + {\hat \lambda} \| a^Ta \|$

without the need for a cross-validation step as $\lambda$ has already been chosen.

This has the benefit of accounting for the best $\lambda$ over all possible values of $a$, weighted by what values of $a$ are most probable. Cross validation is elegant in a sense of efficiently using the data but it feels unnecessarily frequentist.

## My question is: is EM a valid technique for selecting $\lambda$ in this setting or does this suffer from any statistical shortcomings not present with cross validation?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something...why can't you just optimize for $a $ and $\lambda $ directly with penalized ML.

Comment: For one because that's not a convex procedure, so pretty difficult to do practically speaking (unless you have a known procedure in mind you can point me toward). Also, I'm not sure what implications that would have on the out-of-sample error for any new data.

Comment: Okay.  Well in either case I don't understand the last equation you have.  If you integrate over $a $ then how do you choose a specific $\hat a $ to maximize.....you are integrating over all possible values of $a $ right?  I think you can maximize the likelihood in respect to $a $ given a value for $\lambda $ (maximization step).  Then take the average of the squared elements of $\hat a $ to approximate a value for $\lambda $ (the expectation step).

Comment: My thought is that you integrate over $a$ just for choosing $\lambda$ and running EM. Once you have the $\lambda$, you go back to the cost where $a$ is not integrated out and find $\hat a$ via argmax of the L2 cost. I see that my post does not adequately explain this, and is misleading/wrong. I'll update it to make this more clear.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld I have modified the confusing part in my post so it should make more sense now.

Comment: $p (y|x,\lambda) $ is called the marginal likelihood. Maximizing the marginal likelihood in respect to a hyperparameter (as you are doing) is a form of model selection and is discussed  in the bayesian literature.  The challenge is that actually estimating the marginal likelihood is an involved process (and optimizing it is even harder).  There is literature out there on this topic.  If you like I can site some papers for you.

Comment: Good to hear that I'm not blowing smoke! I suppose I would appreciate a couple references on the topic, yes.

Comment: @user27886 to be a bit tongue in cheek, why not choose a completely informative prior that deterministically predicts the data? That will certainly minimize your error.

Comment: @AdamO I am afraid I don't know what you mean by "deterministically predicts the data". Is this sarcasm?

Comment: Yes. "Tongue in cheek" denotes sarcasm. It's an idiom.

Comment: @user27886 we don't use data to estimate priors! Except in sequential analysis.

Comment: @AdamO I realize that that is the standard byline, but doesn't cross-validation use data to select priors, Since selecting $\lambda$ by cross-validation means that test folds are no longer out-of-sample? It's quite possible you're right, but I will need to read more on what I'm now aware is called Bayesian Model Selection and/or Empirical Bayes.

Comment: @user27886 no! Cross validation is used to select and train predictive models. You don't update your models with validation  data.

Comment: @AdamO I understand; This is semantics, but I would consider the out-of-fold samples as "test sets", while validation set(s) are used after you have selected $\lambda$ using the left-out-fold/test sets. Once you select $\lambda$ using the test-sets, they become part of your "training data" and can no longer be used to assess performance for unseen data.